# Wamp not start after configured SSL conf file

Tags: apache, ssl-certificate, wamp, wampserver, httpd.conf

I'm setting up a SSL certificate in WAMP 2.5 and Apache 2.4.9. As I un comment 
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf in http.conf, Wamp not starting.  Here is my ssl confg file and httpd.conf. Please have a look and help.

[SSL Conf File](http://sanjogmittal.com/httpd-ssl.conf)
[Httpd.conf file](http://sanjogmittal.com/httpd.conf)

```
Error in Apache error log 

[Sun Jan 27 10:04:35.018678 2019] [ssl:warn] [pid 4880:tid 564] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Sun Jan 27 10:04:35.034305 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4880:tid 564] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jan 27 10:04:35.034305 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4880:tid 564] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[Sun Jan 27 10:04:35.034305 2019] [core:notice] [pid 4880:tid 564] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Sun Jan 27 10:04:35.034305 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4880:tid 564] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2204
[Sun Jan 27 10:04:35.549913 2019] [ssl:warn] [pid 2204:tid 468] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Sun Jan 27 10:04:35.565540 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2204:tid 468] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For CA certificates you define `Path` instead of `File`

```
SSLCACertificatePath "c:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/key/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt"
```

should be

```
SSLCACertificateFile "c:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/key/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt"
```